# Как работать с Bitcoin на Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, bitcoin

Недавно перешел на Ubuntu и возникла задача переноса и использования своего кошелька под *nix системой.
Подскажите, есть ли быстродействующие решения для установки кошелька?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Multibut](https://multibit.org/), [Armory](http://www.bitcoinarmory.com/), [Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoin.org/ru/download).

Быстрее и проще (в случае с Ubuntu) -- использовать `Bitcoin Core`.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bitcoin-qt
```